# How can I get the highest value generated from within a function using struct C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, struct

So I'm trying to display the account with the highest generated interest but for some reason it isn't working? Any help is much appreciated.  The errors I'm getting are to do with the if statement at the bottom.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int MAXACCOUNTS = 8;

struct Account
{
    int AccountNumber;
    double Balance;
    int DaysSinceDebited;
    double Interest;
};

int main()

{
    double highestInterest = 0;
    int highestInterestAccountIndex;

    Account accounts[MAXACCOUNTS] = { {1001,4254,40,20},{7940,27006.25,35},{4382,123.50,2},{2651,85326.92,14},{3020,657.0,5},{7168,7423.34,360},{6245,4.99,1},{9342,107864.44,45} };

    for (int index = 0; index < MAXACCOUNTS; index++)
    {
        if (accounts[index].Balance > 10000 || accounts[index].DaysSinceDebited > 30)
        {
            accounts[index].Interest = accounts[index].Balance * 0.06;
        }
        else
        {
            accounts[index].Interest = accounts[index].Balance * 0.03;
        }

        cout << "Account number: " << accounts[index].AccountNumber << " Balance: " << accounts[index].Balance << " Interest Paid: " << accounts[index].Interest << endl;

    }

    for (unsigned int index = 0; index < MAXACCOUNTS; index++)
    {
        accounts[index] = { AccountNumber[index], Balance[index], DaysSinceDebited[index] };

        double increment = CalcInterest(accounts[index]);

        if (increment >= highestInterest)
        {
            highestInterest = increment;
            highestInterestAccountIndex = index;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "The account that generated the greatest interest was account " << accounts[highestInterestAccountIndex].accountNumber << " With a total interest of " << highestInterest;


    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

I have to do it in this format as well, using the struct but I cant figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: What are the errors?  Have you stepped through your program with a debugger?

Comment: Why are you reassigning `accounts[index]` in the second loop? Where do the `AccountNumber`, `Balance`, `DaysSinceDebited` arrays come from?

Comment: There's no declaration of `CalcInterest()`.

Comment: from the struct Accounts.  I'm really new to this and struggling a bit.

Comment: You can't use structure members as ordinary variables. `AccountNumber[index]` is not the same as `accounts[index].AccountNumber`.

Comment: I just need it to show the account that generated the highest amount of interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of these lines:

```
    accounts[index] = { AccountNumber[index], Balance[index], DaysSinceDebited[index] };
    double increment = CalcInterest(accounts[index]);
```

You already filled in `accounts[index]` when you initialized it at the beginning of `main()`. There are no arrays named `AccountNumber`, `Balance`, or `DaysSinceDebited`, those are only members of the `Account` struct.

And there's no function `CalcInterest()`, the interest is already in the structures.  So you can change that second line to simply:

```
double increment = accounts[index].Interest;
```

You also have a typo: `accounts[highestInterestAccountIndex].accountNumber` in the last `cout` line should be `accounts[highestInterestAccountIndex].AccountNumber`.

Comment: You have a typo in the last `cout` line, you wrote `accountNumber` instead of `AccountNumber`. Didn't you get an error message pointing that out?

Comment: Once I fixed that it compiled without errors and works.